# how to add data dynamically using for each loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add data dynamically in table from array object, and also I need to add serial number and icons (approve and reject) in action column. But right now am only able to add employee names for array object. How to add serial number and icons in column in this table. plz check image.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJDWK.png

Javascript -

```
const button = document.getElementById('btn2');
const employee = [
    {
        name:'shubham',
        company:'google'
    },
    {
        name:'yash',
        company:'facebook'
    },
    {
        name:'saurabh',
        company:'hcl'
    }
]

const mydiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');

employee.forEach(event =>{
    const td = document.createElement('td');
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.appendChild(td);
    mydiv.appendChild(tr);
    td.innerHTML = event.name
})

button.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    const username = document.getElementById('username');
    const userpass = document.getElementById('userpass');

    if((username.value == "admin" && userpass.value == "admin") && (username.value != "" && userpass.value != "")){
        console.log('yes')
        window.location.pathname = 'dashboard.html';
    }

})
```

HTML -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<h2>Welcome</h2>
<div >
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="mydiv">
        <tr>
            <th>Sr.No.</th>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="function.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is `btn2` in your Html code??

Comment: that is other part, ignore that

Comment: There is no dynamic adding of anything to that Object. You have a table row that has the same length of table data within it. Probably not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
const employee = [
    {
        name:'shubham',
        company:'google',
        action: 'some action'
    },
    {
        name:'yash',
        company:'facebook',
        action: 'some action'
    },
    {
        name:'saurabh',
        company:'hcl',
        action: 'some action'
    }
]

const mydiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');

employee.forEach((event, key) =>{
    const serialTd = document.createElement('td');
    const nameTd = document.createElement('td');
    const actionTd = document.createElement('td');
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.appendChild(serialTd);
    tr.appendChild(nameTd);
    tr.appendChild(actionTd);
    mydiv.appendChild(tr);
    nameTd.innerHTML = event.name
    serialTD.innerHTML = key
    actionTd.innerHTML = event.action
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much Rishi

Comment: @naresh Does this answer your question? If yes, please accept it so that it helps others.

Comment: can you plz let me know how to do that??

Comment: @naresh - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work